# Rewrite Boolean Expression without Parentheses

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a black box processing system that accepts boolean expressions but does not support parentheses. I want to input a boolean expression like this:

```
A && (B || C)
```

However, when I input it as:

```
A && B || C
```

it evaluates expressions as if I had entered:

```
(A && B) || C
```

Is there any way to rewrite my expression to get the desired behavior of A && (B || C) without parentheses? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a relation between precedence but, you can use associative and distributive laws to resolve this.

```
A && B || A && C
```

Truth tables match.

Be careful when implementing this. Not all compilers and languages use the same precedence and evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: No left-right precedence, sorry.

Use the [distributive law](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/%7Ezqiao/Math1130_2009/Chap6.pdf) and the precedence of `&&` to check if either both `A` and `B` is true or both `A` and `C` is true.

#### Solution

`A && B || A && C`

#### Distributive Law

`x ^ (y v z) = (x ^ y) v (x ^ z)`


`x && (y || z) = (x && y) || (x && z)`

```js
function original(A, B, C) {
  return A && (B || C);
}

function mySolution(A, B, C) {
  return A && B || C && A;
}

console.log(original(true, true, true) == mySolution(true, true, true));
console.log(original(true, true, false) == mySolution(true, true, false));
console.log(original(true, false, true) == mySolution(true, false, true));
console.log(original(true, false, false) == mySolution(true, false, false));
console.log(original(false, true, true) == mySolution(false, true, true));
console.log(original(false, true, false) == mySolution(false, true, false));
console.log(original(false, false, true) == mySolution(false, false, true));
console.log(original(false, false, false) == mySolution(false, false, false));
```

Comment: while I like your idea, the truth tables don't match - here is an online truth table generator - http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ if you enter my original expression and then yours, the values for the outputs are different

Comment: I was originally wrong, but worked out the solution using some testing. It looks like @IvanGrasp found the same simultaneously.

Comment: But that evaluator is probably not doing left to right precedence